# Why does `mask_` neutralize `timeout`?

Tags: haskell, exception, timeout

I finally was able to track a weird bug I was having down to the (at least to me) surprising interaction between `mask` and `timeout`:

```
import System.Timeout
import Control.Exception

ack :: Int -> Int -> Int
ack m n | m == 0, n >= 0  = n + 1
        | m >  0, n == 0  = ack (m - 1) 1
        | m >  0, n >  0  = ack (m - 1) (ack m (n - 1))

tryack :: Int -> Int -> IO (Maybe Int)
tryack m n = timeout 100000 {- uS -} $ evaluate $ ack m n

main :: IO ()
main = do
  a <- tryack 3 11
  print a -- Nothing

  b <- mask_ $ tryack 3 11
  print b -- Just 16381 after a few seconds
```

This strikes me as a rather "non-compositional" interaction, as it means that if a library internally uses `timeout`, an externally applied `mask` somewhere up the call-chain may cause the library to malfunction.

So is this a (known) deficiency in the implementation of `timeout` or is it intentional?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What does [`mask_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Exception.html) do?

> Executes an IO computation with asynchronous exceptions masked. That is, any thread which attempts to raise an exception in the current thread with Control.Exception.throwTo will be blocked until asynchronous exceptions are unmasked again.

And what does [`timeout`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/System-Timeout.html) do?

> Wrap an IO computation to time out and return Nothing in case no result is available within n microseconds (1/10^6 seconds).In case a result is available before the timeout expires, Just a is returned. ... A tricky implementation detail is the question of how to abort an IO computation. This combinator relies on asynchronous exceptions internally.

So... `mask_` is preventing `timeout` from delivering its exceptions. That's just how it is.

You just can't use `mask` and have `timeout` work.

Perhaps a better approach would be to use a handler to catch anything but the exception that `timeout` uses?

Comment: Right, it's inevitable since timeout requires the computation to run in the current thread.  A library using timeout should probably fork a new thread to escape the mask.